# How to implement Announcements in Ruby on Rails app with per User control of read/viewed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to implement a site-wide Announcement feature in my Rails app.

Admins would be able to create announcements and define start_date and expiration_date.

I'd also like to know if an User viewed an Announcement, and when he clicked on "dismiss" the Announcement it wouldn't show in the view anymore.

After thinking about it, I am considering creating a `Has Many :through` model association. Basically a `User has_many Announcements through: UserAnnouncements`.

So I would create two new models, one fore Announcements (where admins would set the text, start and end date) and one join table (UserAnnouncements) where I would be able to store the information on each User's status regarding that announcement (`viewed` and `dismissed` basically).

Would that be a reasonable approach?

My main question right now is in the creation of Announcements. I have 15k users, and it takes considerable time to create the anouncements if I do it like this:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  announcement = Announcement.new
  announcement.user = user
  announcement.save
end
```

This takes around 30 seconds to run. What if I had 100k users?

Would a more reasonable approach be create the `Announcement` model and show it to every User, `unless` it had a `HideAnnouncement` model which `user_id == current_user` ? What would an ActiveRecord like this look like?

Comment: I suggest creating an association record AFTER viewing or dismissing announcement . And show the announcement  unless there is a record in the association table with the particular user. Also be sure to index `user_id` and `announcement_id`.  So after creating announcement  you dont have to create additional record for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could build it from scratch, but I like the idea to "not waste time on non-core stuff".

That being said, you could give a try to [Paul Revere](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paul_revere) or [Starbust](https://github.com/csm123/starburst) gems, both of have as goals display sitewide announcements to users.

As example, after setting Starbust, just add an test announcment with `Starburst::Announcement.create(:body => "Our app now features lots of balloons! Enjoy!")`.

If you want to create your own, sneak peeking their source would also be valuable.